# how to resolve issue "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header " on client side using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

I am facing this issue -> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403. 
But I need to resolve this problem on client side only. i cannot code server side. restrictions are javascript only and if possible then ajax. 
can anyone help.

Comment: One solution (Chrome only) is to install the [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)...

Comment: This cannot be solved from javascript. You need to pass `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*"`  in response header from server end.

Comment: @sfletche - useful extension, but damned dangerous unless it is an `opt in` and not a `opt out` access control - and let me say that it's a good thing that there is no (well known) way to defeat cross origin issues like this on the client side

Answer (score 0):

There are few solutions you can follow - 
**1st solution** in chrome browser disabling security [not advised]

- Close your Chrome browser.
- Open your Terminal. Just type this command.

  alias chrome="open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ --args --disable-web-security"
- Re-run your Chrome. If chrome security is successfully disabled, you should see yellow warning bar at the top of the chrome view.

**2nd Solution**
Modifying the dataType parameter to `dataType:'jsonp'`

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'your domain url',
  data: myData,
  type: 'GET',
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function() { alert("Success"); },
  error: function() { alert('Failed!'); },
  beforeSend: setHeader
});
```

**3th Solution** - in serverside put the headers `keys/values` in options method response

```
void handleRequest(Request request, Response response) {
    if(request.method == "OPTIONS") {
       response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow- Origin","Your_Domain")
       response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",  "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
       response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
   }
}
```

**4th Solution** If the `setHeader` dosen't work then you can try with `addHeader`

Use `addHeader`  --> `response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` into your php file server side code as follow:

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $username= "root";
    $pass = "12354";
    $dbname = "taxi_booking";

    $conn = mysql_connect($host, $username, $pass);
    mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);

    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
?>
```